# Topology of Convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am having some difficulties in understanding the concept of topology induced by convergence? especially how the weak convergence induces weak topology? Does anybody know a good reference which elaborate this in an easy manner (without resorting to net and filter)?

thanks,

Comment: That's not a good direction. Defining a topology in terms of convergence is a nightmare. The fundamental thing is the topology. For TVS topologies, the neighbourhoods of $0$. Characterisations of convergence follow directly from that.

Comment: Well, defining a topology in terms of convergence can be very practical. A good source with numerous examples is the book [Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels - Treves](http://www.amazon.com/Topological-Vector-Distributions-Kernels-Mathematics/dp/0486453529)